# echo command to serial port in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I want to echo something from my Ubuntu host to some device.

It works well if I use putty or minicom.

However, it doesn't work if I do echo from the shell terminal:

```
echo "cmd" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

From my device, I saw that the first letter of the cmd is received correctly while the second one received is ASCII bigger than 200. I also have tried to use the "stty" command to adjust the serial communication settings but didn't help. Does anythone know why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

First You need to set the  tty device settings and then you need to transmit the data whatever you want

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 -parity cs8 -cstopb
```

OR

```
stty -speed 9600 < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Now Send data:

```
echo "cmd" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried but they do not help. I think for second command it's "speed" instead of "-speed". I tried both 115200 (which is the device speed) and 9600. Didn't work. However, from "stty -a" command, I do see "cs8" and "-cstopb" option while there is no "-parity" or "parity" .

Answer (score 0):

I have not sofar found any stty parameters, which makes echo work.

Echo works, if you have minicom or cat running in the background. You do not need to send any characters nor set any parameters in those programs.
So, there is some settings in the Linux setting, which handles the trafic.

Linux Mint 21, Arduino, /dev/ttyUSB0